# Mapping the index of values in an array that match a specific value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Disclaimer, I'm a beginner.

I have an array that is 16 digits, limited to 0's and 1's. I'm trying to create a new array that contains only the index values for the 1's in the original array.

I currently have:

```
one_pos = []
    image_flat.each do |x| 
        if x == 1 
            p = image_flat.index(x)
            one_pos << p
            image_flat.at(p).replace(0)
        end
    end
```

The image_flat array is [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

With the code above, one_pos returns [3, 3] rather than the [3, 5] that I'd expect.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using each_with_index (http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) on your array.

```
image_flat = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

one_pos = []
image_flat.each_with_index do |value, index| 
  if value == 1 
    one_pos << index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

> Where am I going wrong?

When you call

```
image_flat.index(x)
```

It only returns first entry of x in image_flat array.

I guess there are some better solutions like this one:

```
image_flat.each_with_index do |v, i|
  one_pos << i if v == 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Maxim, this really helps me understand why .index wasn't working for me!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most elegant solution here:

```
image_flat.each_index.select{|i| image_flat[i] == 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you are looking for a solution that doesn't reach out of the enumerable block although it does require a chained solution.

```
image_flat.each_with_index.select { |im,i| im==1 }.map { |arr| arr[1] }
```

Its chained and will require an additional lookup so Gena Shumilkin's answer will probably be more optimal for larger arrays.

This was what I originally thought Gena Shumilkin was trying to reach until I realized that solution used each_index instead of each_with_index.